# Eviando respostas de uma enquete php via array para um email usando a função mail php

Tags: php, array

Bom dia a todos, gostaria de saber se estou de recebendo os valores do meu formulário de forma correta e enviando por email usando um array para listar perguntas e respostas da enquete.

segue o código.

```
 $meuArray = array( 0 => "$pergunta_principal", 1 => "$primeira_opcao", 2 => "$segunda_opcao", 3 => "$terceira_opcao", 4 => "$quarta_opcao");

                while($lista array($meuArray)) {

              .'<b>'. echo $lista['pergunta_principal'];.'<br/><br/>
                <b>Primeira Opção  R:</b> '.echo $lista['primeira_opcao'];.'<br/><br/>
                <b>Segunda Opção   R:</b> '.echo $lista['segunda_opcao'];.'<br/><br/>
                <b>Terceira Opção  R:</b> '.echo $lista['terceira_opcao'];.'<br/><br/>
                <b>Quarta Opção  R:</b> '.echo $lista['quarta_opcao'];.'<br/><br/>
                '
                } //fim do while
```

Comment: 1 - Não entendi o uso do while. 2 - Tem muitos erros aí, você está concatenando uma string com a função echo, tá errado. 3 - Melhore a indentação. 4 - Use aspas duplas e jogue as variáveis diretamente. 5 - Cadê o código pra enviar o email?

Comment: vou postar tudo ..

Answer (score 0):

```
 $Perguntas = array(
   "Primeira Opção"  => "$primeira_opcao",
   "Segunda Opção"   => "$segunda_opcao",
   "Terceira Opção"  => "$terceira_opcao",
   "Quarta Opção"    => "$quarta_opcao"
 );

 // cria variavel para armazenar as msgs.
 $msgParaEmail = '';


 foreach($Perguntas as $key => $p_valor) {
    $msgParaEmail .= '<b>'.$key.' R:</b> '.$p_valor.'<br/>';
 }

 // Função fictícia  
 enviarEmail(teste@email.com,$msgParaEmail);
```

Comment: Showww mas como enviar por email ? eu digo as linhas quebradas ..como o foreach vai listar entende..e agradeço desde-já

Comment: Fiz uma edição.

Comment: ai que eu nao entendi tipo na $msgParaEmail = "" onde tá vazio eu chamo uma variável qualquer ppra receber os valores ? ou deixo como está ..

Comment: deixa como está! eu criei ela só para receber os dados fora do escopo do foreach...

Comment: Bom dia, meu querido não está pegando os valores vindos do formulário ..esqueci de te dizer que esse form ai ..é um efeito jquery.. onde tá o while ele fica repetindo até o cliente ( administrador quiser parar de colocar perguntas.. entendeu. ) quando ele finaliza.. os dados vem pra essas variáveis e monta-se o formulário.. até ai tá feito, missão de hoje resgatar essas respostas desse formulário que o administrador gerou e enviar por email .